# PowerShell function returns duplicates in DataTable

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell 5.0 function which I'm trying to use to return a data table that is used in some downstream activities. However, it seems to return duplicates everytime I place this into a variable as so:

```
function GetTable {

    $tbl = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable" 
    $tbl.Columns.Add("testNum").DataType = [string]

    for($i=0; $i -lt 3; $i++){
            $tbl.Rows.Add($i)
    }
    Write-Host $tbl.Rows.Count
    return $tbl
}

$test = GetTable
$test.Rows.Count
```

This outputs:

```
3
6
```

Why does the function duplicate the data when returning the data table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `Add` method returns the added element so it also gets to the pipeline. You can simply fix that by pipe the result to `Out-Null`:

```
function GetTable {

    $tbl = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable" 
    $tbl.Columns.Add("testNum").DataType = [string]

    for($i=0; $i -lt 3; $i++){
            $tbl.Rows.Add($i) | Out-Null
    }
    Write-Host $tbl.Rows.Count
    return $tbl
}

$test = GetTable
$test.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Would this be the same case for the Columns.Add method? Or is the fact that the datatype is being specified to it prevent that from happening?

Comment: In PowerShell, everything that you call that returns something and you don't assign to a variable or pipe to anything gets put to the pipeline and will be returned even you don't use the `return` keyword. So if the Columns.Add method returns anything the answer is yes.